# Dropdown list values not being populated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My aim is to show values in a dropdown list.

My code gets the data from database but the dropdown list is not being populated

```
$scope.CountryID = xxx.CountryID;
```

Comment: Your question is completely vague and therefore can not be answered. If you want an answer you will need to learn how to ask questions that can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show data in `DropDown` list you need use `ng-repeat`

eg:-

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="cate in category" value="{{cate.id}}">{{cate.name}}<option>
</select>
```

In above code `category` is a `$scope` with data from DB

Comment: <select class="form-control" ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" ng-model="CountryID" ng-change="GetStates()">
                                        <option value="{{CountryName}}">{{CountryName}}Select Country</option>
                                    </select>   I had writen this way but in not Bindidng values in drop